# How i can install mariadb odbc connector on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mariadb, odbc, ubuntu-20.04

How i can install mariadb odbc connector from sources https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-odbc? i tryed install by using this https://blog.sleeplessbeastie.eu/2018/01/08/how-to-install-and-configure-mariadb-unixodbc-driver/ howto, but it can't installed
it require libssl1.0.2

Comment: In general it is recommended to use a (well maintained) repository and packages rather than installing software from source

Comment: but no exsits in repo

Comment: Just go download it from their web site, then.

Comment: https://downloads.mariadb.org/connector-odbc/3.1.10/ - only sources here

Comment: I've made a note to get the links fixed.

Answer (score 1):

From the [MariaDB ODBC Connector knowledge base page](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-connector-odbc/) page there is a [MariaDB ODBC Binary downloads link](https://dlm.mariadb.com/browse/odbc_connector/87/878/)

Comment: Thanks, yes this is binary package, but how do you then install it ? I can guess that the archive has to be extracted from the root of the system, but then how is it setup/configured ?

Comment: Follow the first link to the [install instructions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/about-mariadb-connector-odbc/#installing-mariadb-connectorodbc)